# Call C# boolean function from Javascript code using PageMethods

Tags: c#, javascript, mysql, sql

Ok so i have a loop which makes buttons and sets their id and i want to check if btn.id exists in sql table then to set the buttons color red if not then to set the button color green simple as that.

```
 function InIT() {
            for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

                var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");

                btn.id = i ;                    
                btn.style.cssText = 'height:50px;width:50px;margin:5px;';
               if (PageMethods.Check(btn.id) == true)                                      
                {
                    btn.style.cssText = 'background:red;height:50px;width:50px;margin:5px;';
                }
                else
                {
                    btn.style.cssText = 'background:green;height:50px;width:50px;margin:5px;';
                }

                document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(btn);
                //this is a div where i create the buttons


}
```

Now the C# function 'Check' is below where Table name is "Book" and this table has one column "Name" so i want this function to return true if there exists a row in the column Name where its name is the passed value 'ID'.

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static bool Check(string ID)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SimpleDB"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
                      IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Book Where Name = @ID)
                      SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                return (result == 1);
            }
        }
```

But the problem is that whenever i call the Check function like this

```
if (PageMethods.Check(btn.id) == true)
```

But this is never true and all buttons are set to be green no matter if their ID's name is the Name column of the SQL table or not.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

you can call c# code behind from JS, here's how

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-excecute-a-c-Method-63380306

Answer (score 0):

change your javascript function to this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var btn;
        function InIT() {
            debugger;
            for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

                btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");

                btn.id = i;
                btn.style.cssText = 'height:50px;width:50px;margin:5px;';
                PageMethods.Check(btn.id, OnSuccess, OnFailure);

            }
        }

        function OnSuccess(data) {
            debugger;
            if (data) {
                btn.style.cssText = 'background:red;height:50px;width:50px;margin:5px;';
            }
            else {
                btn.style.cssText = 'background:green;height:50px;width:50px;margin:5px;';
            }

            document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(btn);
        }

        function OnFailure() {
            alert('Error');
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: changed to this and it does not alert me 'Error' so i guess it works fine and i guess function calls OnSuccess but buttons stay uncolored so nor red or green.

Comment: run the solution in internet explorer the debugger on the functions(as written in code above) will be called and you can check what is going wrong

Comment: i added `alert('Success');` to OnSuccess function and it does not alert me so i guess `PageMethods.Check(btn.id, OnSuccess, OnFailure);` does not seem to work properly

Comment: Then it must be something else, because the code you have pasted above works for me

Comment: Im calling the InIt function like this `window.onload = function () { InIt(); };` maybe this is where im searching the error